# If I take a home equity loan out can it "add" PMI to my mortgage?

Tags: united-states, 401k, home-equity, pmi

So ironically I took out a 401k loan to avoid PMI on a property we purchased. I've recently left the job where I had the loan and want to repay the balance, but will need to borrow in order to do so.

If I take out a home equity loan that "reduces" the overall equity in my home below 20% could that cause my mortgage lender to add PMI to my mortgage? Or are my mortgage terms based on the fact that I had 20% equity when I purchased the house?

This may be a silly question but I honestly don't know the answer! Having a hard time finding it on google as well.

Comment: You typically can't get a home equity loan that brings your equity under 20%.

Comment: The mortgage lender remains "primary" and they won't care (as much), because they'll get paid first in a liquidation.  The HEL/secondary mortgage may insist on insurance.

Comment: Do you have another job lined up, does it have a 401(k) plan, and does that plan allow rollover of assets+loan together from a previous employer?

Comment: @CO That is interesting I did not know that! Since I’m right at the threshhold that may influence my ability to take out a home equity loan. Thank you for the info!

Comment: @Ben Voight Hey I do have another job lined up but it is with a new company. I will not likely be able to get a 401k set up in the 60 day window as they are still getting their 401k options established. I’m only employee #3 so it will probably be a little later this year before we have a 401k established. Would definitely be a good option if it existed!

Comment: How much is the loan?

Comment: @CharlesFox lol well my loan is around $165 and the house is worth somewhere near $210-$215 as last appraised (maybe 3 months ago - we'll see what the market is doing). If I can only take out up to 80% of the value of the home that doesn't give me too much wiggle room, but I might be able to split the difference between an equity loan and a personal loan.

Comment: Have you asked your 401(k) administrator about the eligibility requirements for a COVID19 distribution? How much is left in the 401(k)?

Comment: @CharlesFox I'm just starting my investigation now. My desire is to replace the funds within the 401k so as not to pay the tax penalties and not to rob my retirement account. Even a 9% or 10% interest loan is better than the 30%-40% penalty I will pay for not replacing the funds. Once I sell or rent another property I own I can likely repay any loan quite quickly. I don't know if this answers your question - thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am self answering as I've worked this all through.

- Taking out a HELOC (Home Equity Line of Credit) on my property will *not* add PMI back to my mortgage
- My local Credit Union is willing to provide a HELOC up to the full appraised value of the home
- Due to current market demand this process is expected to take up to 6 weeks.
- I have since taken out a personal loan to ensure that I can pay back the full balance of the 401k loan before it is counted as a distribution

  - It was crucial that I not pay the tax penalties and remove that much money from my retirement accounts.
- I am in the process of selling another property and will use some of those proceeds to repay the personal loan.
- If I choose not to repay the full amount of the personal loan with my sales proceeds then I will take out a HELOC to pay off the remainder of the personal loan

  - The personal loan has an exceedingly high interest rate, like 10% as it is unsecured

So that's it! It's very much possible, though it will depend upon an individual's situation and their credit score, income etc.

**Additional notes based on comments to the question:**

- 401k loans cannot be rolled over except in very special circumstances, such as the company employing the individual being acquired.
- My current employer offers a SIMPLE IRA so rolling over wouldn't be an option under any circumstance.
- From talking to my accountant (who I probably should have called in the first place lol) he mentioned that COVID19 distributions must have occurred during the time that the market was impacted by the virus

  - I took out this 401k loan late last fall, so I would not be eligible for that exemption.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting an answer, it is quite detailed.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Absolutely! Hope it can help someone else as well :)